# Django package to display a horizontal bar of images with left/right scrolling

Tags: django, image

All right, I *know* that the Django package I'm looking for already exists, somewhere in "djangopackages," I just don't know the right terms to use to look for my choices.

The effect that I want is a horizontal bar, with left/right scroll buttons, which shows a set of image thumbnails in rotation.

I'm quite certain that this "has been done to death," but I haven't stumbled on it yet.  Therefore, to save myself a bit of time, I thought I'd simply ask the community ... what search term or category should I use on "djangopackages.com?" I'm not trying to manipulate the images – as in actually "rotating" them ... but, "what is this actually 'called?'"

Comment: The term you are looking for is "carousel".

Comment: But I don't find a "djangopackages.com" category by that name, nor does a search by that term turn up anything useful.  Nevertheless, "solved."

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the term **is:** "carousel."  So, I'll consider this question "answered" and will eventually be allowed to flag it as such.

*Thanks, community!*